# Write an Eigen Matrix to json file using nlohmann json using to_json method

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have an Eigen matrix defined -

```
template <typename T>
using Vec3 = Eigen::Matrix<T, 1, 3, Eigen::DontAlign | Eigen::ColMajor>;
using Vec3d = Vec3<double>;
```

I try to write Vec3d to json file like below -

```
template <typename T>
void to_json(json& j, const Vec3<T>& v) {
    j = {{"X", v(0)}, {"Y", v(1)}, {"Z", v(2)}};
}

// Usage
Vec3d test(1.f, 2.f, 3.f);
frameJson["Vec3d"] = test;
```

Output is stored as an `array` and not like the way specified in `to_json`, seems like it is not entering the `to_json` ??

```
"Vec3d": [
 1.0,
 2.0,
 3.0
]
```

But I want it like the way specified in `to_json` like below -

```
"Vec3d": [
 "X": 1.0,
 "Y": 2.0,
 "Z": 0.0
]
```

Is something wrong in the way templated `to_json` is implemented.  How do I make this work.

PS : Also how would the templated `adl_serializer from_json()` look like while reading ?

Comment: Don't know why it was downvoted, the problem is [reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/b3P1xze46) with just some small changes. It looks like either nlohmann or Eigen already implements Eigen Matrix serialization to json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I failed to find where the default `Eigen::Matrix` json serializer is implemented, but to have your custom serializer working, just put it inside `Eigen` namespace:

```
namespace Eigen
{
    template <typename T>
    void to_json(json& j, const Vec3<T>& v) {
    j = {{"X", v(0)}, {"Y", v(1)}, {"Z", v(2)}};
}
```

Alternatively, like suggested in the documentation for [third-party types serialization](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#how-do-i-convert-third-party-types), you can write `adl_serializer` specialization:

```
namespace nlohmann {
    template <typename T>
    struct adl_serializer<Vec3<T>> {
        static void to_json(json& j, const Vec3<T>& v) {
            j = {{"X", v(0)}, {"Y", v(1)}, {"Z", v(2)}};
        }
        static void from_json(const json& j, Vec3<T>& v) {
            v(0) = j["X"];
            v(1) = j["Y"];
            v(2) = j["Z"];
        }
    };
}
```

Second option might be preferable in general, as it doesn't pollute your third-party namespace.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nd9j8ja5r)

Comment: Thanks so much, also how would the from_json look like ? Have update my question. 
Basically I couldnt wrap my head around `adl_serializer`

Comment: Well, basically the same, but opposite direction - see the edit in the answer. Then you can get your value from json like that: `auto vec = myJson["Vec3d"].get<Vec3d>();`

Comment: oh, cool, `from_json` is also under the `adl_serializer` struct, thanks a lot
I can extend this to other scenarios as well